# ¿Cuáles son los servicios SOAP de SiatInfo?

Tags: siatinfo

impuestos en Bolivia esta implementando el ***Sistema de Facturacion Electrónica*** que otros países ya implementaron, cuales son los servicios web SOAP que se necesitan para desarrollar un sistema facturador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

los servicios SOAP son:

- https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos.gob.bo/v2/FacturacionCodigos?wsdl
- https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos.gob.bo/v2/ServicioFacturacionElectronica?wsdl
- https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos.gob.bo/v2/FacturacionOperaciones?wsdl
- https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos.gob.bo/v2/FacturacionSincronizacion?wsdl

para mas detalles leer la [documentacion](https://siatanexo.impuestos.gob.bo/index.php/implementacion-servicios-facturacion/autenticacion/token-de-autenticacion)